# Why isnt the Tailwind CSS text decorations applied

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I am trying to have a line-through in my text , once you hover over the text I want the line-through to disappear.When I use Tailwind Play and enter this exact code the class is applied and works properly, so IDK what the deal is.

I am using react.js

here is my current code:

```
`<td className="px-4 py-3 border-black border text-xl ">
  <ul>
    {job.responsibilities.map((responsibility, resIndex) => (
      <li
        key={resIndex}
        class="text-decoration-black line-through decoration-8 hover:no-underline "
      >
        {responsibility}
      </li>
    ))}
  </ul>
</td>;`
```

I am using tailwind version 3.3.2 and have run the build to update my output.css file. All my other tailwind classes are applied except for this one

I have tried simplifying the class and general trouble shooting via DevTools

Comment: Consider checking that the `content` file globs sufficiently cover the file that the code is in.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote `class` instead of `className`. Probably that's the problem.